# maven works separately but fails within ANT

Tags: java, maven, ant, dependencies

There is relevant part of ANT task

```
<target name="package-qwerty" depends="filter-qwerty">
    <artifact:mvn pom="pom.xml">
        <arg value="package" />
        <arg value="-Dmaven.test.skip=true" />
        <arg value="-Dorg.apache.struts.scope=compile" />
        <arg value="-P qwerty" />
    </artifact:mvn>
</target>
```

and it fails on attempt to load dependent files

```
    <!-- Sitemap Parsing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemap-parser</artifactId>
        <version>0.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

but the same pom.xml works fine when executed outside ANT.

```
mvn -DskipTests=true compile
```

**any ideas ?**

looks like ANT uses something different for mvn then maven does itself.

Apache Maven 3.1.1.
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

Your command configured in ANT is different than command you running from command line

You are running this in ANT:

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dorg.apache.struts.scope=compile -P qwerty
```

(do package without tests with profile qwerty and property org.apache.struts.scope=compile)

it obviousle isn't:

```
mvn -DskipTests=true compile
```

(do compile without tests)